# Using a secondary filter query with join on child document block-join

Tags: solr

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a secondary filter query on child document query when using a block join query.  Data is like below:

```
[
  {
"id":1,
"title":"good",
"content_type":"parent",
"_childDocuments_":[
{
"id":"1_1",
"type":"color",
"value":"orange",
"start":"2015-01-03T14:32:00Z",
"end":"2015-01-03T14:34:00Z"
},
{
"id":"1_2",
"type":"shape",
"value":"square",
"start":"2015-01-03T14:32:00Z",
"end":"2015-01-03T14:34:00Z"
}
]
},
{
"id":2,
"title":"bad",
"content_type":"parent",
"_childDocuments_":[
{
"id":"2_1",
"type":"color",
"value":"orange",
"start":"2015-01-03T14:32:00Z",
"end":"2015-01-03T14:34:00Z"
},
{
"id":"2_2",
"type":"shape",
"value":"square",
"start":"2015-01-03T14:35:00Z",
"end":"2015-01-03T14:37:00Z"
}
]
}
]
```

Ultimately, I'm looking to query for parent documents that contain "color:orange" and "shape:square" within the same time range.  I've approached the problem from multiple angles with no success.  In this approach, I'm trying to use apply a filter query to the childDocuments condition of a block-join query.  For example, in the following query (which doesn't work), the idea is to use a join query in the childDocuments filter query to find all child documents with the shape:square and return those child documents that have the same start date.  The secondary query would then be applied to only return "color:orange" children from that subset.

{!parent which="content_type:parent"}(({!join from=start to=start}type:shape AND value:square) AND type:color AND value:orange)

So, the result in the end would only be document 1.